# Custom Marker Icon For Globe API

Tags: javascript

After long search, i found that there is no option to set the marker icon something custom. I am now trying to plot my markers in two different types. I need to visualize it distinctly, by using two separate icons, is there any options to set custom marker icon in Globe. Quicker response will be really helpful ,as i am at the edge of the deadline.

I am using simple Globe api

```
    var earth = new WE.map('earth_div');
      WE.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(earth);

    {% for last_place_marker in last_place_markers %}
    var marker = WE.marker([{{last_place_marker.destination_lat}}, {{last_place_marker.destination_longit}}]).addTo(earth);
    marker.bindPopup("<b>{{last_place_marker.destinaton}}</b><br>{{last_place_marker.when}}<br /><span style='font-size:10px;color:#999'>{{last_place_marker.description}}</span>", {maxWidth: 150, closeButton: true});
    //.openPopup()
    {% endfor %}

    {% for target_marker in target_markers %}
    {% if target_marker.target_destination_lat %}

        var marker = WE.marker([{{target_marker.target_destination_lat}}, {{target_marker.target_destination_longit}}]).addTo(earth);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>{{target_marker.target}}</b><br>{{target_marker.when}}<br /><span style='font-size:10px;color:#999'>{{target_marker.description}}</span>", {maxWidth: 150, closeButton: true});
        //.openPopup()
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    earth.setView([25, 79], 2.5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globe API is an opensource api which will not provide custom marker icons, open google maps will be better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value in CSS style.

```css
<style>
    .we-pm-icon {
    background-image: url(http://madridhoy.info/imagejpg.php?url=http://campinadigital.me/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/160620-planas.jpg&rs=1)!important;
    }
</style>
```